# security issue with system commands

Tags: php

In order to start processing a batch command, I need to call a different script from the page that I am on, but I need to reassure that the was not called by anyone else.

Let me explain.

I need to contact my Credit Card Clearing company to issue a batch of transactions. these transactions MUST ONLY bwe taken out due to a specific user request.

If by mistake the command is taken out just by someone else this is a complete disaster.

I thought to take the script I need to call outside the website scope, for example a folder that neighbours the "includes" folder, and call it with a parameter, something like:

```
"php ../../batch.php?id=5&process=all"
```

But the thing is, that inside **batch.php** I cannot verify that the command was issued by anyone. I mean, when I process my own pages I always check if the user is logged in using SESSION variables. 
But by executing a script, I believe this cannot be done as the system calls itself, or can it?

Is there a way to tell if the user is a confirmed user who executed the script?

How would you do it ?
Thanks!

Comment: do you already have a user management system?

Comment: then why not use it to identify yourself as the only one who can run the script.

Comment: ok. The website is serving lots of users. The script is supposed to run for many of them, providing the script is run with the correct ID of that specific user using it. But, since the script is run with a system command, all I have is GET parameters that anyone can simply type in. How do I prevent that? How do I check the session parameters of that user from that sensitive script?

Comment: do you mean your call the script with exec() ?

Comment: yes. How do I know it was a scriptA that called that scriptB, and not a user just typed that to his URL ? or on the other hand, how can I overcome this problem

Comment: put batch.php outside the web root, then it can only be called by another php script (or some one with server access), then you can verify them in the script that makes the call to batch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If by mistake the command is taken out just by someone else this is a complete disaster.

Sure. But what do you think?!

```
$ php ../../batch.php?id=5&process=all
```

This is just invoking a command (`php`) via shell. Under a POSIX system, there always is a *user* invoking the command. Consult your system manual to find out about the user. A user is *always* authenticated in a shell environment. That's what it is for (at least in part).

So probably your problem is not authentication but just the point how you invoke the script. As you have not given much information in your question about the specifics of the context this is happening in, it just can't be answered (more specifically to the things already being written).

If you really want to ensure that a specific script is only called under very specific circumstances, create a user on the system only for that circumstance, don't share the passphrase then only this user can invoke that command. Create a shell script out of it (shebang PHP) and make the file only available to that user.

Comment: The website is serving all users. Unregistered users can access certain pages, but not all of them, so of course, to get access to the DB, I have a special user created for it, for example. Question is, if I can access user's SESSION in the foloowing: scriptA.php (serving the user - has the command system("scriptB.php?id=5&process=all")), where scriptB.php is accessing the DB with very sensitive data, so I would like scriptB.php have the user authenticated by SESSION parameters, but I don't know how to do this. Or else any registered user will be able to hack that scriptB.php

Comment: You can pass along the session to a PHP shell script by providing the session id. Probably that's already your missing link.

Answer (score 0):

can you include it in the page?
edit it to accept extra arguments - username/userid/etc.
if you can't edit it, have a wrapper script that does the checks and calls it

ultimately, you should make the calling script robust enough - SRP

Comment: I can make the calling script robust as I will, it is the access to the called upon script I am worried about. If A calls B, with parameters like ID so A.php would go through the phase where it calls B.php?ID=7. this is great. but what prevents malicious users from simply typing in their browser B.php?ID=12 ?

Comment: But then, if the calling script is "robust", it won't allow that to happen, isn't it?